# How to change the pivot point position of a text object?

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to change the pivot point position of a text object without converting it to a curve or mesh?

Comment: You can (simply) use the SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+C command to adjust the position where you want to place the object's origin.
READ https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 3D Cursor where you want the object center to be and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor*, or *Origin to Geometry* if you want to center the origin.